# Feasible solution with positive $m+1$ components

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matrix-rank

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Let 
\begin{equation}
\min \hspace{0.3cm} \{c^Tx: \text{ s.t. } Ax = b, x \geq 0 \}
\end{equation}
Suppose that $x$ is a feasible solution to the previous LP, with $A$ an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $m$. Show that there is a feasible solution $y$ having the same value (i.e. $c^Ty = c^Tx$) and having at most $m+1$ positive components.

Regards

Comment: Seems like linear algebra let m = $c^T$x, find a solution to Ay=b AND $ $c^T$y = m. Augment matrix A to  A:c and vector b to b:m Thus, you have m+1 equations with n unknowns. So, you have at most m+1 basic variables. And, the system always has a solution because the system doesn't have full rank.

Comment: Essentially, you're moving the objective into the constraints

Comment: @Ragnar Thank you for your support.